# microsoft Dynamics CRM Group by

Tags: group-by, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a list of customers (incl. data). Each customer is attached to a owner. See example below.

[image]

I would like to create a table in a dashboard (it is called a list in dynamics) where I summarize stats per user. Columns could be User - #meetings Q1 - #meetings Q2 - .... Total Revenue.

[image]

I have been unable to find anyway of doing a group by.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

basically you are looking for reporting ways, where you have data and you want to show/report it.

You have 3 ways.

1. create SSRS Report and embed it as Iframe or webresource in your dashboard.
   In your ssrs report you can group by and do all sort of things basically done for reporting
2. Or create powerBI report and embed it as Iframe or webresource in your dashboard. With PowerBI you probably will need Pro license and so on.
3. You could also create PCF control/ custom html webresouce and show data required as grid with all your grouping and so on.

With SSRS you do not need any license as it is included out of boy.
With PCF/HTML grid you have higher code development but you have control what to show and how to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create Rollup field on User entity and rollup fields for Stat 1 as sum on that field and count on account relationship.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/define-rollup-fields

Answer (score 0):

FetchXML provides [groupby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/use-fetchxml-aggregation#group-by) capabilities.

This example counts the number of lines per quote:

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='quotedetail'> 
       <attribute name='quoteid' alias='quotelinecount' aggregate='countcolumn' /> 
       <attribute name='quoteid' alias='quoteid' groupby='true' /> 
       <order alias="quotelinecount" descending="true" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

If your org is online, the [SQL endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/cds-sql-query) is also available (in preview).